# How much protection can be given by a password encrypting short, common strings?

Tags: security, encryption

I have a device that sends lists of domains accessed to a server where they're stored. A client-side app can display these to authorized users.

I'd like to encrypt the domain names so a copy of the database doesn't reveal the domains. My concern is that a typical-length password encrypting short, possibly known strings (domains) would be quite vulnerable to a brute-force attack.

This would need to use a password set on the device by the user and entered into the client-side app, but not stored on the server. The domain names need to be encrypted separately without a salt because they need to map to a consistent value in the database.

Would using the password to encrypt the domain names provide enough protection?

Comment: What encryption algorithm are you using?

Comment: I'm not committed to any particular algorithm, but will need to find something I can run on the OpenWRT device and in browser JavaScript.

Comment: Doesn't your data store support encryption at rest?

Comment: As long as you do things right (use key stretching and proper encryption algorithm) this will be ok.